# Очищает ли JVM стек вызовов после StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, jvm, числа-фибоначчи

Пусть **N** это N-ое число Фибоначчи, при вычислении которого возникает переполнение стека вызовов, а **K** это K-ое число Фибоначчи, которое будет вычислено успешно.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
        fib(N);
    } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
        fib(K);
    }     
}

public static long fib(long n) {
        if(n == 0) return 0;
        if(n == 1) return 1;
        return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
}
```

При первом вызове fib(**N**) стек переполняется, так почему же становится возможным дальнейший вызов fib(**K**) при переполненным стеке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключение всплывёт через все кадры стека, завершая выполнение соответствующих вызовов. Следовательно, в момент срабатывания блока `catch` в стеке будет только кадр метода `main`.

Comment: Тем самым вычищая стек при обратном пути, кажется понял, но получается что отлавливание неконтролируемой ошибки и дальнейшая обработка в этом случаи оправдана? Хотя тот же К.Хортсманн пишет, что это очень серьезная ошибка и поток должен быть прерван, да и обрабатывать его не зачем, а в моем случаи поток возобновляет свою работу.

Comment: Хорстман, скорее всего, имеет ввиду то, что обработка ошибки вычисления `fib(5000)` не позволит вам получить результата `fib(5000)`, а потому смысла не имеет.

Comment: Этот пример не из книги, это моя импровизация. Допустим пользователь вводит такое значение, которое приводит к Stackoverflow, я его перехватываю и обрабатываю, сообщая что мол введите значение по меньше, но по идеи я не должен обрабатывать такого рода ошибки ведь они неконтролируемые.

Comment: Да, правильнее в таких ситуациях падать с ошибкой.

Comment: Мы подошли к вопросу, который не дает мне покоя. Почему правильнее?

Comment: Во-первых, в подавляющем большинстве случаев возникновение `StackOverflowError` - признак критического бага. Баги нужно исправлять, а не обрабатывать, работать с причиной, а не следствием. Во-вторых, это исключение может привести к ошибочному состоянию программы, которое вылезет позже ещё более разрушительным и непредсказуемым багом.

Comment: на самом деле зависит от степени критичности ПО которое Вы пишете. Если программе ну никак нельзя падать ни при каких обстоятельствах - то это другой подход к разработке и он регулируется специальными требованиями. Хотя в большинстве случаев там используются уже другие языки программирования

Comment: Несколько искусственный, но [очень интересный пример](https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2020/02/01/jvm-inside-out-part-4/) того, как программа может перейти в фатально некорректному состоянию.